# Create xml template from xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have a requirement to create some XML templates based on some XSDs, but I'm not sure what's the best approach to take.

My input would be these XSDs, and my output must be something like this:

```
<root>
 <tag1>${root.tag1}</tag1>
 <tag2>
  <tag3>${root.tag2.tag3}</tag3>
 </tag2>
</root>
```

I know I can use JAXB to generate Java classes, but I'm not so sure about how to create the XMLs and populate them with the placeholders and I showed in the example.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.